# Select2 is not working with no errors as to why

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to get a very basic example of select2 working but I am running into issues.  There are no errors in my console saying that select2 is encountering errors, but the test select box is only displaying the default.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/select2.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#sel").select2();
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
<body>
```

Is there something that I am just not seeing?

- I am using select2 4.0.2 downloaded from nuget, is there a 'better' version to go with?

Comment: Shouldn't that select be in a `<form>`?

Comment: From what I am seeing in their documentation, they do not put their selects in a form, nevertheless its worth trying at this point.

Comment: The <form> did not work

Comment: You're missing [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Either that or put the javascript at the bottom of the body.

Comment: I could have sworn I had tried that earlier, but it does seem to work now... I'm not entirely sure why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try do this.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/select2.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sel").select2();
});
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
<body>
```